# Where is the latest version of WMD editor?

Tags: markdown, wmd, wmd-markdown

The latest version of WMD on [derobin's GitHub page](https://github.com/derobins/wmd) is quite old and seems to be unmaintained. Following the social graph, the [OpenLibrary WMD](https://github.com/openlibrary/wmd) page looks much newer but still isn't the newest. Where is the authoritative source or blog or website? So I can follow development and discussions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this post over on stackmeta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35084/is-there-an-official-stackoverflow-version-of-wmd-editor-available-for-download